# Decorator to time specific lines of the code instead of whole method?

Tags: python

Lets assume a simple method :

```
def test_method():
    a = 1
    b = 10000
    c = 20000
    sum1 = sum(range(a,b))
    sum2 = sum(range(b,c))
    return (sum1,sum2)
```

To time this method using a decorator, a simple decorator would be :

```
from functools import wraps
def timed_decorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
        start = time.time()
        result = f(*args, **kwds)
        elapsed = (time.time() - start)*1000
        logger.debug("f::{0} t::{1:0.2f} ms".format(f.__name__, elapsed))
        return result
    return wrapper
```

Now if I want to time specific lines of `test_method` say line 4 `sum1 = sum(range(a,b))` , the current implementation involves inline coding like:

```
 def test_method():
        a = 1
        b = 10000
        c = 20000
        start = time.time()
        sum1 = sum(range(a,b)) # timing specific line or lines
        elapsed = (time.time() - start)*1000
        logger.debug("This part took::{1:0.2f} ms".format(elapsed))
        sum2 = sum(range(b,c))
        return (sum1,sum2)
```

The intention is to use the decorator to time lines M to N of a specific method without modifying the code in the method.
Is it possible to inject such logic using a decorator ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a context manager.

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def time_measure(ident):
    tstart = time.time()
    yield
    elapsed = time.time() - tstart
    logger.debug("{0}: {1} ms".format(ident, elapsed))
```

In your code, you use it like

```
with time_measure('test_method:sum1'):
    sum1 = sum(range(a, b))
```

---

By the way, if you want to improve your code, you can use the Gaussian Sum Formula (explained [here](http://betterexplained.com/articles/techniques-for-adding-the-numbers-1-to-100/)) instead of `sum(range(a, b))`.

```
def sum_range(a, b):
    r_a = (a ** 2 + a) / 2 - a
    r_b = (b ** 2 + b) / 2 - b
    return r_b - r_a
```

Comment: I was looking for way to time those lines without modifying the original method.

Comment: You cannot do that without modifying your original code. Judge logically, you can time code externally only if it is a whole unit, like `module`, `function`, etc. As for only some lines of code, @Niklas R has given a pretty nice and pythonic way of achieving your goal.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple solution with a custom context manager:

```
class elapsed:
    def __enter__(self): self.start = time.time()
    def __exit__(self, *args): print("%.1f ms" % ((time.time() - self.start)*1000))
```

Example usage:

```
with elapsed():
    sum1 = sum(x ** 2 for x in range(1, 1000000))
# 547.0 ms
```

More about this: [Decorator-like syntax for a specific line of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51077539/decorator-like-syntax-for-a-specific-line-of-code)

---

Another solution: here is a slight variation of @NiklasR's answer without `logger` but `print`, and a ready-to-run example:

```
import contextlib, time

@contextlib.contextmanager
def time_measure(ident):
    tstart = time.time()
    yield
    elapsed = time.time() - tstart
    print("{0}: {1} ms".format(ident, elapsed))

with time_measure('hello'):
    sum1 = sum(x ** 2 for x in range(1, 1000000))

# hello: 0.577033281326294 ms
```

Comment: In my implementation, this results in seconds. I changed the code in my implementation to use "{0}: {1} s".format(ident,elapsed)

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of is to use sys.settrace() and record time when handling "line" event in the tracer function. But one caveat is, the practice of setting a tracer may cause the time recorded to be inaccurate.

The general idea is:

1. Set a tracer function in the decorator that wraps the target method.
2. Get the line number for the first line of this method, with `FLN = inspect.currentframe().f_lineno.`
3. In the tracer function, handle "call" event and return a local tracer function to trace the "line" events in the scope. [Read this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) if you are confused.
4. Within the local tracer function, get the current line number LN, 
   if LN-FLN == M, record the start time; if LN-FLN == N, record the end time, the time taken to execute lines M to N is endtime - starttime.

code:

```
import sys
from functools import wraps
import time
import linecache

_func_name_ = None
_func_ln_ = 0
_start_ = 0
_end_ = 0
_timestamp_ = 0

def trace_calls(frame, event, arg): 
    global _func_name_, _func_ln_
    def trace_lines(frame, event, arg): 
        global _timestamp_
            if event != 'line':
                return
        line_no = frame.f_lineno
        filename = frame.f_code.co_filename
        if line_no-_func_ln_ == _start_:                        
            _timestamp_ = time.time()
            print "%d %s TS:%d"%(line_no, linecache.getline(filename, line_no)[:-1], _timestamp_)

        elif line_no-_func_ln_ == _end_:
            _timestamp_ = time.time() - _timestamp_
            print "%d %s"%(line_no, linecache.getline(filename, line_no)[:-1])
            print "Lines %d to %d of %s takes %d seconds."%(_start_, _end_, _func_name_,  _timestamp_)      

    if event != 'call':    
        return   

    co = frame.f_code      
    _func_ln_ = frame.f_lineno  # record the line number at function entry point
    func_name = co.co_name 

    if func_name != _func_name_:
        return             
    return trace_lines

def time_lines(start, end):
    global _start_, _end_
    _start_, _end_ = start+1, end+2     # function name takes a line, end is inclusive
    def inner(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            global _func_name_
            _func_name_ = f.__name__    
            sys.settrace(trace_calls)
            f(*args, **kwargs)
            sys.settrace(None)
        return wrapper
    return inner

@time_lines(2,4)
def tested_func():
    print "Enter target function"
    time.sleep(2)
    time.sleep(1)
    time.sleep(3)
    print "Exit target function"

if __name__=="__main__":
    tested_func()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty ugly, and not very stable code. but the only way I found to do this task is to exec the code of the function again, after injecting your code.
Something like this:

```
import inspect
import re
import time

def inject_timer(f,n,m):
    codelines = inspect.getsourcelines(f)[0]
    ident_lvl = re.search("^[ \t]*",codelines[n]).group(0)
    codelines.insert(n,ident_lvl + "start_longJibrishTo_preventCollision = time.time()\n")
    codelines.insert(m+2,ident_lvl + "elapsed_longJibrishTo_preventCollision = (time.time() - start_longJibrishTo_preventCollision)*1000\n")
    codelines.insert(m+3,ident_lvl + """print("f::{0} t::{1:0.2f} ms".format("""+f.__name__+""", elapsed_longJibrishTo_preventCollision))\n""")
    #print "".join(codelines)
    exec "".join(codelines) in globals()

def test_method():
    a = 1
    b = 10000
    time.sleep(2)
    c = 20000    
    sum1 = sum(range(a,b))
    sum2 = sum(range(b,c))    
    return (sum1,sum2)

inject_timer(test_method,3,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

A decorator can only decorate callables (e.g. functions, methods, classes). A single line or a group of lines are not callable as long as you do not wrap them in their own callable.

For timing a unit of your code you should choose an appropriate number of repetitions. The goal is to make sure that the execution time is longer than just a few micro or milliseconds, otherwise the measurement error will be too large.

Did you have a look at the `timeit` module?

Comment: Agreed with `callables`, but is there a way to access lines M to N of the callable inside the decorator ?

Comment: No, there is no mechanism to specify "line N to M" of unit U. The Python interpreter does not keep track of line counts within single units of code. That would be huge overhead.