# Decorator-like syntax for a specific line of code

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

Linked topic (but not duplicate): [Decorator to time specific lines of the code instead of whole method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30433910/decorator-to-time-specific-lines-of-the-code-instead-of-whole-method)

I know how decorators are usually used for Python functions.

**Is there a similar concept/syntax for single lines of code?**

Example: with

```
def measuretime(lineofcode):
    start = time.time()
    lineofcode()
    print time.time() - start
```

then

```
@measuretime
im = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(data)))
```

would be interpreted like

```
start = time.time()
im = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(data)))
print time.time() - start
```

Notes:

- I know measuring execution time like this is not optimal, it's better to use [`timeit`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8220801/1422096), etc. but it's just a random example to show what I'm looking for (decorators for single lines of code)
- I'm looking for a 1 or 2 lines of code solution (+ definition of the function of course). If the solution takes more than 2 lines of code (i.e. more than something like `@measuretime`), then it's probably better to give up and just do the normal:

  ```
    start = time.time()
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(data)))
    print time.time() - start
  ```

Comment: For test? Use `jupyter` and `%timeit`.

Comment: @Sraw I already mentioned `timeit` in the question, and also I'm not using jupyter/ipython but Python in script mode, i.e. `python script.py`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do stuff before and after a line of code, a [context manager](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) would be appropriate:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import time

@contextmanager
def measuretime():
    start = time.time()
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        print(time.time() - start)

with measuretime():
    do_stuff()
```

Comment: Nice solution, seems like I'm looking for!

Answer (score 2):

No. Decorator is basically a function that takes another function as an argument and returns "decorated" function. @decorator is just a syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

No, but the closest thing to your goal would be using a context manager to cover one line of code.

```
import time

class timer(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = time.clock()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.end = time.clock()
        self.interval = self.end - self.start
        print(self.interval)

with timer():
    [i for i in range(100000)]
```

This outputs the following on my computer:

```
0.005583688506699192
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing in the language, although you can try looking at `jupyter` (formerly known as `ipython`). It has `%%timeit` shortcut.